# Can I do a cvs commit using a file for the cvs comments?

Tags: cvs

I would like to be able to do a cvs commit, but provide multi-line comments from a file instead of letting cvs invoke the editor. Is this even possible?

Comment: Did you mean `cvs update` or `cvs commit`?

Comment: @ArialdoMartini Thanks, you're right. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [-F flag](http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.12.13/cvs_16.html#SEC140) thus:

```
cvs commit -F file <files to commit>
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably do the job:

```
cvs commit -m "$(cat file)" modified_file.c
```

Comment: This relies on bash to cat the file, it won't necessarily work with other shells (e.g. csh)

Comment: @ADW `cat` is a binary not a bash built-in

Comment: Sorry, badly worded comment, I meant that the use of "$(command)" is a bash thing.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you did mean commit, not update, which does not require comments, you could do

```
cvs commit -m `cat file_containing_multiline_comments` file_to_commit
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the commit message contains spaces as the backticks will expand each word in the file to a separate argument to cvs.